# ng-click function only works the first time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have setup a simple ng-click function on a div that once clicked should change the color of a different div. Simple enough except it only works on first time I click the div...then nothing :( I am just trying to get functionality for a toggle function which I will use all over for different things.

HTML: (this code is part of a loop)

```
<img ng-click="changer()" src="{{m.img}}" style="width:100%;min-height:480px;max-height:600px;z-index:1;">
```

...

```
<div style="background-color:{{colorblur}}; width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.colorblur="red";

  $scope.changer = function () {  
        if($scope.colorblur="red"){
          $scope.colorblur="yellow";
        }
        else{
          $scope.colorblur="red";
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be better if you use ng-src and ng-style attributes for variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
 if($scope.colorblur="red"){..
```

to

```
 if($scope.colorblur === "red"){...
```

Comment: That's why I love this site..I can find out I'm an idiot within minutes. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3):

use === instead of =

```
if($scope.colorblur === "red"){
```